# Jquery remove append input

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var n=1;

        $("#add").click(function(){
            if(n<8){
            $("#form").append("
                <input type='text' name='input_" + (n++) +"'/>
                <input type='button' id='remove_" + (n++) +"' value='REMOVE'/>");
            }
        });     
    });
```

I have a Jquery add input text.

How can I remove the specific input.

http://jsfiddle.net/JvW3L/

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: What should trigger the removal?

Comment: I hope you know what `n++` does. Because the input has another n value than the remove button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class for your button like this -

```
$("#form").append("<input type='text' name='input_" + (n++) +"'/><input type='button' class='remove' value='REMOVE'/>");
```

And to remove input and button -

```
$('form').on('click','.remove',function(){
   $(this).prev('input').remove();
   $(this).remove();
   n--;
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/JvW3L/4/

Answer (score 5):

Assuming an element with the `id` of 'deleteInput' is to be clicked to trigger the deletion:

```
$('#deleteInput').click(function(e){
    // in case it's an element with a default action:
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form input').last().remove();
    n--;
});
```

The above will simply remove the *last* `input` element added, and decrement the `n` variable.

If, on the other hand, you want to remove a specific `input`, other than the last:

```
$('.deleteInput').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev('input').remove();
});
```

This assumes that the element, with a class of `deleteInput` will immediately follow the `input` to be removed. In this case I'm leaving `n` as-is, and leaving you to find some way of re-using the vacated/emptied 'slot' for the `input` to be recreated (since a simple decrement would probably cause two elements to (invalidly) share the same `id`.

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#form").on("click", "input[id^='remove_']", function () {
    $(this).prev(':text').remove();
    $(this).remove();
    n--;
});
```

Since the `inputs` are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler.
[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JvW3L/3/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$("#remove_").remove();
```

(Assuming that you want to remove the second input with `id='remove_'`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select an element, using jquery selectors. After you have selected it, you can do various things, one of them is removing it.

You can select elements by name, attribute, type, it's position in DOM or id.

In your case, the simplest would be, for input of id "input_3":

```
$("#input_3").remove();
```